# Organizer badge for a question I didn't retag

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I just got an [organizer badge](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/badges/5/organizer?userid=12081) for a question I didn't retag.

Looking at the [question's edit history](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/323/revisions), it shows me as having changed a tag.  All I did was update a link.

This is a rather peculiar bug.

Answer (score 3):

The question was automatically re-tagged when you edited it because [interface](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interface) is a [synonym](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/user-interface/synonyms) of [user-interface](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-interface) (and so is [ui](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ui)).

I reproduced the behavior by making edits to [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/revisions/1b99975b-b334-496f-a57a-6466a9d33ec5/view-source) (but not manually editing the tags of course). Presumably, this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).